# How to export pseudo fields display configuration to code

Tags: entities, features

How can I export the configuration of pseudo fields as set from the display configuration for my entities types and their bundles ? When exporting a *normal* fields instance (with [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features)) its display settings, for each available view mode, are exported with it. But I cannot find how to export the settings for the pseudo fields such as the *History* field of a User entity and the *File* field for a [File entity](http://drupal.org/project/file_entity).

Comment: Pseudo fields isn't quite the right term for that but I'm having a hard time coming up with the right one.

Comment: Ah, well core seems to call them "Non-field elements" which isn't super descriptive. Actually I'm wrong, they're also referred to as pseudo-fields. Learned something new.

Comment: Does your feature export the content type? It seems like that additional field info is exported on nodes that are "owned" by a feature.

Comment: No, the feature-module does export the content type. It depends on several content-type defining modules and configure them to provide a coherent user experience (same fields ordering on edit and view, same image styles, etc.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strongarm will do this because [`field_bundle_settings()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_bundle_settings/7) stores the settings in a huge variable called `field_bundle_settings`. There is a patch to move it into several variables, but it'll be variables nonetheless.

Edit: I guess the core source code counts as "official source", doesn't it?

Comment: FYI, the variable is now split up - e.g. field_bundle_settings_user__user (field_bundle_settings_[entity_type]__[bundle])

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds)? It allows for that and much more. It might be overkill, but it just solves your issue AND is exportable in features.

See [mortendk post](http://morten.dk/blog/heya-display-suite) on Display Suite, particularly his [slides](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/51287/2011-dcstockholm-displaysuite.pdf).